# Prepend a URL to columns match

Tags: sql, database

I am trying to fix a table in a WordPress database where full URL should exist but don't.

I want to select all columns where `meta_key = __wpdm_icon` then out of all of that prepend all columns with `http://local-site/wp-content/plugins/` if the URL isn't already there.

I was looking at this but I don't think it is precise enough for this operation.

```
UPDATE tbl SET col=CONCAT('test',col)
WHERE col NOT LIKE 'test%';
```

I tried this:

```
UPDATE wp_fbjd_postmeta SET meta_value=CONCAT('http://local-site/wp-content/plugins/',meta_value)
WHERE meta_value NOT LIKE 'http://local-site/wp-content/plugins/';
```

Comment: you did not include the wildcard `%` in your try.  That query would not work correctly without the wildcard

Comment: basically `startswith%  %endswith  %contains%`  your query looks for exact match and would probably replace every record in the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a % wildcard to your WHERE clause check, otherwise it will never execute

```
UPDATE wp_fbjd_postmeta SET meta_value=CONCAT('http://local-site/wp-content/plugins/',meta_value)
WHERE meta_value NOT LIKE 'http://local-site/wp-content/plugins/%';
```